When hooking using Frida, certain locations are not hooked with Error(unable to intercept function at 0040101D; please file a bug at value)
First of all, I apologize for my English skills.
i'm hooking a simple example through frida.
However, there was a problem in progress, but my skills are not good, so I don't know what to search for and get through.
If you know the answer, you can let me know, or I'm asking if there are any keywords I can search for.
The questions are below.
During hooking, some of the locations of the target program are not hooking properly.
target program with disassembler
occured error in frida
**Error: unable to intercept function at 0040101D; please file a bug  at value (frida/runtime/core.js:408)  at <eval> (C:\Users\lapla\Documents\codeengn\01.js:21)**
All parts except that part are hooking normally, but I'm not sure why.
I wonder if 32bit is the problem, so it's the same even if I install python 32bit, and it works same even if I hooking same intruction "inc esi", "dec eax" in different locations.
The problem only occurs in the above position, so may I know why?
The hooking target is the file at the following URL.(password is codeengn)
github.com/codeengn/codeengn-challenges/raw/main/RCE_Basic/...
And this is the code I used.
var Base = Module.findBaseAddress('01.exe');
var interloc = Base.add(0x101D); 
console.log(Base); 
console.log(Instruction.parse(ptr(interloc)).toString()); 

Interceptor.attach(interloc, {
   onEnter(args) { 
      console.log('onEnter');     
      var reg = this.context;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(reg, 0, 2)); 
      console.log(reg.eax); 
      reg.eax = ptr('0x3')        
   },onLeave(retval) {     
      console.log('onLeave');     
      var reg = this.context;     
      console.log(JSON.stringify(reg, 0, 2));        
   } 
}); 

I installed and ran a 32-bit python, but the same error occurred. Additionally, i try hooking the same command in another location, it will be normally hooked.  I don't even know how to search because I have little knowledge. Is there a way to know the cause?

On PC side it doesn't matter if you run 32 or 64 bit python. What matters is only frida-server.

@Robert When the attach was not working, I installed and used the 64-bit fireda on the 64-bit python, so I tested it by installing the 32-bit python and frida. I found out that the conclusion doesn't matter. I wonder if the pc side you mentioned is when the attach function works after the frida agent is inserted to the program.
